# Totally discontinuous manner in Proposition 4.3 of Chapter 8 of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry

Tags: algebraic-topology, riemannian-geometry

Picture below is from the 8 Chapter of do Carmo's Riemannian Geometry. In this part, I feel the  author writes very briefly.  I can't understand the red line.

My problem:  $p:\tilde M \rightarrow M$ is universal covering and local isometry. I think
$$
\Gamma = \{\varphi :\tilde M \rightarrow \tilde M ~|~ \varphi \text{ is  isometry and } 
p\circ\varphi = p
\}
$$
But I don't know why $\Gamma$ acts on $\tilde M$ totally discontinuous.

> [image]
> [image]

Comment: The group of [deck transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covering_space#Deck_transformation) always (when the space is nice, which includes manifolds) acts totally discontinuously ([this should be relevant](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/55726/properly-discontinuous-action)): this is an algebraic-topology property. If the universal cover is endowed with the pullback Riemannian metric (hence we call it a Riemannian covering), thenthese transformations are isometries, by construction of the pullback metric!

Comment: @Didier  Thanks.